# VBA Textbox's change affect second textbox and vice versa

Tags: vba, textbox

On my form I have more textboxes, but two of them are special. It's textbox with name `tbVolume` and textbox with name `tbWeight`.

If I change `tbVolume`, by other parameters is computed value for `tbWeight`, but when I added same procedure to `tbWeight` (to compute value for `tbVolume`), it creates some kind of cyclically link, because change of volume changes weight, change of weight changes volume, etc...

Does it exist some argument of `tbVolume_Changed()` / `tbWeight_Changed()` which can tell to procedure if value is changed by user or by application?

Or do you have another idea how to solve this twin-textbox problem?

Comment: Try: `AfterUpdate`...

Comment: @Fusseldieb
I tested `AfterUpdate` - it's the same effect in my case. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oh.. Finally it was so easy, only two new booleans and everything works fine:

```
Dim editingVolumeByApp As Boolean
Dim editingWeightByApp As Boolean

Private Sub tbVolume_Change()
  If editingVolumeByApp = False Then
    '...
    editingWeightByApp = True
    tbWeight.Value = finalVolume * CDbl(tbMatDensi.Value)
    editingWeightByApp = False
    '...
  End If
End Sub

Private Sub tbWeight_Change()
  If editingWeightByApp = False Then
    '...
    editingVolumeByApp = True
    tbVolume.Value = finalVolume * CDbl(tbMatComplCoef.Value)
    editingVolumeByApp = False
    '...
  End If
End Sub
```

And it works fine :-)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `tbWeight_Change()` or `tb_Volume_Change()` you could use the following:

```
Private Sub tbWeight_Exit(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)
    ' do everything you want to do
End Sub
```

and of course:

```
Private Sub tbVolume_Exit(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)
    ' do everything you want to do
End Sub
```

You change the value of the textbox, exit it via tab or mouse click and the other value of the textbox will change.

If you want a parallel output while writing in the textbox you can use an extra textbox just for displaying the calculated value.